# Sqlite3 unable to open database file specific directory

Tags: python, database, flask, connection, sqlite3-python

I'm trying to make a database connection through flask/sqlite3.

Everything is working fine, the database also works fine, but the problem is the path is a bit weird.

When I try to make a connection like this:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("databases\\testgpt.db")
```

it doesn't work: it'll give an error saying

> Sqlite3, OperationalError: unable to open database file

On the other hand when I try to manually give the path it does work, like this:

```
 connection = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\adria\\OneDrive - Hogeschool Leiden\\Documenten\\RAc\\Periode 2\\Werkplaats 2\\wp2-2023-mvc-1b4-bforbest\\databases\\testgpt.db")
```

Now the problem is: this is a group project so I have to push everything through github. We have to work with the same code, now you can imagine that the second part only works on my computer (since I'm using my local computers path name), but somehow I have to make it work like shown in the first part

I tried everything. I even showed my groupmembers, but for all of them the first part works fine, but somehow for my pc and even my laptop it doesn't work.

Comment: `python
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(basedir, "databases\\testgpt.db")
`

Could do the trick for you. Of course the databasefile has to exist before you can connect to it.

Also take a look at this tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) It shows you an much easier way to handel databases in flask